# One-eyed, tentacled aliens that disguise themselves as humans

Tags: identify-this-movie, identify-this-tv-show, science-fiction

I saw this when I was *very* young, so my memories are spotty.

I cannot recall if this is a movie or a TV episode (older), nor whether it was color or black and white (though my memories include color, so it's entirely possible.)

I remember aliens that were large, their bodies made up of thin tentacles (shaped kind of like *Cousin It* from the Addam's Family) and one eye in the top center of their bodies. They disguised themselves as humans, and only one man on the show could see them. I remember this man laying on a doctor's table or something and looking up, and the guy above him was one of these aliens. I think he flipped out and no one could figure out why because no one else could see the creatures.

There was also a woman who I believe was... psychic or magical or something? In my memory, she looked like a genie (I do not know if this is accurate) with a high brown pony tail and poofy genie pants. She used her abilities to disguise herself as one of the creatures. You could tell the difference because her eye was a different color than the other creatures. (In my memories, hers was blue, the creatures were dark?) They discovered her, I think, and she had to flee and had trouble changing her form back into a human because her powers were weakened.

I don't remember how this all ended, but this has been bothering me *forever* and I have never found any help. Can anybody help?

Comment: Can you give us an idea of when 'VERY young' means?

Comment: Well, I was probably about 6-8, so this was mid 80's... This show/film had an older-era feel to it. I've had Doctor Who, It Came from Outer Space, the Crawling Eye and such suggested to me, but I have yet to find a solid-feeling match. I actually purchased the two films and those are not right.    ...This has driven me so nuts, there have been times I wondered if I didn't have an incredibly elaborate dream and/or am crazy. :P

Comment: I Think that movie was "They Live" made in 1988.

Comment: To me it reminds me of a recent movie monsters vs aliens

Comment: [Related](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=w7NeRiNefO0) :P

Comment: This is amazing, I had the exact same question looking for this show! Watched when I was a little kid, the monsters gave me nightmares, couldn't remember what show it was. I couldn't remember that many details, and I thought it was a movie, and in black and white (heh, my folks only had a black and white TV back then :)

Answer (score 11):

That sounds like the two-part **Space 1999** episode [The Bringers of Wonder](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Bringers_of_Wonder,_Part_One).

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately the YouTube video is no longer available, but as a childhood watcher of Space1999, this seems a very plausible answer, so I found a picture of them instead. +1

Comment: I just finished watching this two part episode. This is still a very enjoyable show. Classic 70's sci-fi! This has to be the right answer it matches the question's description exactly.

Comment: Here's another Youtube link to the episode: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=D1EzanunBdU

Comment: YES. YES!!!!!!!!!!!! It is absolutely that episode of Space 1999! Thank you *SO* much! You have no idea how long this has tormented me... to the point where people were telling me I must have made it all up. After watching the episode, I jumped up and cheered and danced in a circle. That is absolutely the right answer and I thank you with every ounce of my geekdom. I am so lucky to have stumbled onto this site with such amazingly knowledgeable people. You are the best! Thank you!

Comment: That's great @Mia.  I've noticed that you have a new registered account - with a different login from the account you asked this question with.  You gain the 30 reputation from your question if you merge accounts.  You can follow the instructions here ... http://movies.stackexchange.com/help/user-merge

Comment: My existence is justified!

Comment: Thank you! I had the EXACT same question and against all odds here I find the perfect answer! Found it through Bing's image search, when I saw it I knew 'that's it!'